# Kotlin: How to check if field's value is in Array or not in FireStore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have below fireStore structure. It has `diary` collection and `users` collection.

When I draw data from diary collection in my App, I want to check two things.

1. If this **diary** is blocked by logged-in user or not.
2. If this **diary user** is blocked by logged-in user or not.

So I will user `diaryId` of diary collection for 1st, and `userId` of diary collection for 2nd.

My idea is `users` collection will have `blockedDiary` ArrayField and `blockedUser` ArrayField.

And in App I will run `users` collection first and then run `diary` collection as using `whereNotIn` to compare diaryId exists in blockedDiary or userId exists in blockedUser.

```
        userDB.document("$userId")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                var blockedUser = document.data?.getValue("blockedUser") as ArrayList<String>
                var blockedDiary = document.data?.getValue("blockedDiary") as ArrayList<String>

                diaryDB
                    .whereNotIn("diaryId", blockedDiary)
                    .whereNotIn("userId", blockedUser)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
```

But this throws error `A non-empty array is required for 'not_in' filters.`.

Because I set default array of blockedUser and blockedDiary as empty array [] since some user doesn't block any diary or user.

How can I compare with empty array ?

Or is there any good way to implement my purpose other than this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var blockedUser = document.data?.getValue("blockedUser") as ArrayList<String>
var blockedDiary = document.data?.getValue("blockedDiary") as ArrayList<String>
```

in above lines of code , you are having `blockedUser` and `blockedDiary` as an arraylist then you can simply use it's method `isNullOrEmpty()` which will return true in case when arraylist variable is null or empty so you can do code something like this

```
var storeBuilder:MentionReturnTypeOfWhereNotIn ? = null
if(blockedDiary.isNullOrEmpty().not()){
             storeBuilder = diaryDB
                    .whereNotIn("diaryId", blockedDiary)
}

if(blockedUser.isNullOrEmpty().not(){
   if(storeBuilder == null){
     storeBuilder = diaryDB.whereNotIn("userId", blockedUser)
   }else{
     storeBuilder = storeBuilder.whereNotIn("userId", blockedUser)
   }
}
                   
var tmp = if(storeBuilder == null) diaryDB else storeBuilder
 
                    tmp.get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
```

You may need to manage about conditions as i just tried to optimise code but sure about `isNullOrEmpty` method